# How to compare the mutiple column values for single row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to compare the column values for same row number.

Have a table like below with Columns are 1 to 12. Here have given the sample data for  5 columns. I need to do compare for  1 to 12 columns which is having the same value( Value can exists across any of the columns from 1 to 12)

In Below example.

for Key 1 has column value is same between (Column1 and Column3). We are not considering the columns which are having value as 0(Zero). Hence excluding the Column2 , Column4 and Column5 from result sets

```
key Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
-------------------------------------------
1   123.45  0       123.45  0        0
2   456.23  0       789.13  0        0
```

Can you please shed some lights on this? Thanks!

Comment: Please show us your current query and the issue you are facing

Comment: Row with key = 2 also has Column2 = Column4, Column2 = Column5, Column4 = Column5 - so why isn't that row considered for output? You need to explain in **more detail and better clarity** what you're looking for .....

Comment: just use `select key from tableName where colunm1=colunm3` if you consider only those two columns. Else it will bit complex. Add more details for better understanding.

Comment: I have updated my query @Dumal- Value can be across any of the columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` **expressions** as per your requirement in the `where` clause.

try the following:

```
declare @t table ([key] int, Column1 float, Column2  int, Column3  float, Column4  int, Column5 int)
insert into @t select 1, 123.45, 0, 123.45, 0, 0
insert into @t select 2, 456.23, 0, 789.13, 0, 0

select * from @t
where (case 
            when Column1 = Column3 then '1' 
            else '0' end) = 1
```

Please find the db<>fiddle demo **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=03367572a67d0a45ff9aee4492feb6b3)**.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly and the *requirement to compare the column values for same row number* means that you want to get all rows, that have matching values in some of the columns, the next statement is a possible solution. You need to get the values from each row as a table using `VALUES` table value constructor and count the duplicates:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   [key] int,
   Column1 numeric(5, 2),
   Column2 numeric(5, 2),
   Column3 numeric(5, 2),
   Column4 numeric(5, 2),
   Column5 numeric(5, 2),
   Column6 numeric(5, 2),
   Column7 numeric(5, 2),
   Column8 numeric(5, 2),
   Column9 numeric(5, 2),
   Column10 numeric(5, 2),
   Column11 numeric(5, 2),
   Column12 numeric(5, 2)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   ([key], Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8, Column9, Column10, Column11, Column12)
VALUES
   (1, 123.45, 0,    123.45, 0, 0,    1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
   (2, 456.23, 0,    789.13, 0, 0,    0,   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
   (3, 123.45, 4.01, 123.45, 0, 4.01, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 123.45)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.[key], v.ColValue
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
      ('Column1', Column1),
      ('Column2', Column2),
      ('Column3', Column3),
      ('Column4', Column4),
      ('Column5', Column5),
      ('Column6', Column6),
      ('Column7', Column7),
      ('Column8', Column8),
      ('Column9', Column9),
      ('Column10', Column10),
      ('Column11', Column11),
      ('Column12', Column12)
) v (ColName, ColValue)
WHERE v.ColValue <> 0
GROUP BY d.[key], v.ColValue
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY d.[key]
```

Result:

```
key ColValue
1   123.45
3   4.01
3   123.45
```